# IE 11 still submits form without .submit() inside click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I had a tough time wording my question.

Basically when a submit button in a form is clicked I want the button disabled and the button text replaced with a font awesome icon until the POST request goes through. I have the following jquery.

```
  $('div').on('click', '.btn-disabler', function() {
    $(this).append("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse btn-loader'>").disable(true);
    $(this).find('.btn-label').addClass('invisible');
    $(this).css("background-image", "none");
    if ($(this).parents('form') && !$(this).hasClass('btn-facebookauth')) {
      $(this).parents('form').submit();
    }
  });
```

And the button part of my form.

```
<form>
   <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-button btn-disabler">
      <span class="btn-label">Log in</span>
   </button>
</form>
```

My problem is IE 11. In IE with the above code, on click, the button text disappears but the fa icon doesn't show, the button is just blank. The form submits fine.

When I remove the if statement:

```
  $('div').on('click', '.btn-disabler', function() {
    $(this).append("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse btn-loader'>").disable(true);
    $(this).find('.btn-label').addClass('invisible');
    $(this).css("background-image", "none");
  });
```

the button shows the icon correctly and also submits the form? Why is the form submitting when I have removed .submit()? In chrome when I remove the if statement, the icon for the button changes correctly, but the form doesn't submit it just hangs (as expected).

I'm basically trying to troubleshoot the icon not appearing after clicking the submit button in IE while it works fine in chrome.

Comment: have you tried returning false?

Comment: Give an id to your form and write a submit handler in jQuery. Inside the submit handler, add an event.preventDefault(); . This stops the form from being submitted.

Comment: @2pha where would I put that?

Comment: well, instead of putting the listener on the button itself, which submits the form anyway, you could put a submit listener on the form itself. You have not "removed" the submit, you are listening for "click" on the submit button.

Comment: _Why is the form submitting when I have removed .submit()?_ It's browser's default behavior, button inside a form will always submit the form when you click it. To change that you need to capture the click event and call `event.preventDefault()`, which will stop every browser's default actions related to the event.

Comment: @Hp93 When I remove the if statement, why does the form not submit in chrome, but does submit in IE?

Comment: It does submit in this example that I've just created, tested with Firefox/IE/Chrome [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r5uc5zd7/). Regarding your issue with IE, if you still need help, consider update your code. I have an error running this line `.disable(true);`

Comment: @Hp93 all I needed to do was add event.preventDefault(), thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript

```
// wait for document ready before trying to attach listener.
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add a submit listener to the form
  $('#myform').submit(function(e){
    // save this jquery object into a variable as we might access this a few times. In this case it will be the form.
    var theform = $(this);
    // save the button to a variable.
    var thebtn = theform.find(".btn-disabler");
    // prevent the form from submitting (could also return false at the end of this function)
    e.preventDefault();
    thebtn.append("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse btn-loader'>").disable(true);
    theform.find('.btn-label').addClass('invisible');
    thebtn.css("background-image", "none");
    if (!thebtn.hasClass('btn-facebookauth')) {
      theform.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

html

```
<form id="myform">
   <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-button btn-disabler">
      <span class="btn-label">Log in</span>
   </button>
</form>
```

All the above is untested

Answer (score 1):

The submit button is supposed to submit the form, so it works as expected in IE. If you want to manually submit the form by theform.submit() use a button of type button.

```html
<form>
   <button name="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary submit-button btn-disabler">
      <span class="btn-label">Log in</span>
   </button>
</form>
```